# How to call a class of java from another module

Tags: java, android, module, dependencies

I have a project with the structure

android/src/com.x.y/A.java

core/src/com.x.y/B.java

I want to call a method from A.java in B. java. I have searched the internet for solutions i have added the lines

```
implementation project(path: ':core', configuration: 'default')
```

in android's build.gradle and

```
implementation project(path: ':android', configuration: 'default')
```

in core's build.gradle file.

It builds with success but i cannot call the class from B. java

Comment: Are you saying that both of the class files are in the same project or that you are trying to call a class from project A in project B?

Answer (score 0):

Import the statement

```
import android.src.com.x.y.A.*;
```

Then make an object of A.java as follows:

```
A a = new A();
```

Then use it's methods in class B wherever you want.

```
a.pqr()
```

For further guidance and understanding the concepts, go through official documentation.
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/

Comment: It doesnot work as B.java doesnot recognize the namespace android.src.com.x.y.A.*;

Comment: @Taskeen Hi, Did u get any solution for this? Even I want to implement in same way but no result. If you got let me know it will be helpful. Thanks

Comment: No i wasn't able to find any solution to it.